# Add overflow menu items to dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Attempting to recreate a similar behaviour to that of [DELIVEROO](https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/london/bloomsbury?postcode=WC1E%207HJ)
[image]

**What They Do**

The horizontal menu outlining the categories houses a large collection of list items each with variable widths. The main menu shows all that the viewport can handle, with the remaining list items being added into a 'more' drop down. The site has three behaviours, each of which I would like to achieve.

1. Hide list items in the 'more' dropdown that appear on the primary horizontal menu.
2. Give an `.active` status to the list item in both menus, but if item is in dropdown, they change the name and styling of the dropdown.
3. Following from `2.`, if a dropdown list item is active and the window is resized, the menu returns to normal and the active list item is shown on the main horizontal menu.

**How They Do It (learned so far)**

Two menu's load with the exact same information and list items. The main horizontal menu has a hidden overflow that hides everything that is listed beneath the height of the container.

Javascript plays a heavy roll i'm sure to calculate and find out what items are being show in the viewport, and which items are not. However, the site is built in `React.js`, and minified, I cannot read the raw js.

**Where to start**

I have prepared a fiddle below to start from. Now I would like to try and replicate these three functionalities to this menu.
Could anyone offer support/assistance? RAW JS is fine, but jQuery preferred

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v79cr3vb/)**

...

**CODE SAMPLES**

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.link-bar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.link-bar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.context-bar {
  flex: 1;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.context-bar-link, .grouped-link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}


.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="link-bar">
  <div class="context-bar">
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 123</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 13</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 774</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1234</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 12</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 9</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 10</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1422</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 12</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 9</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 10</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1422</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 12</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 8</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 9</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 10</a>
    <a href="#" class="context-bar-link">Item 1722</a>
  </div>
  <div class="grouped dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="grouped-link">Item 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it would be much easier if we use any `library/framework` like `angular` or `knockout`

but for now, i used `jquery`

here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rf63sd1n/

Comment: This is a great solution. So as I understand it, what you have done is taken the height of the menu and the offset of the menu as the base. All child objects within the menu that are outside of the offset are added to the submenu. This is my understanding... one further question though. If I were to add an item to the menu <p class="nolink">Interests:</p>, how would I exclude this from the script. I have included this in a new fiddle for context: [FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1ba3gxuw/)

Comment: Also - finally, what if the category count means that ALL categories display on the top row. Could an additional argument be added to say if there are no menu items below to remove the 'more' button?

Comment: @LukeC Please mark the answer as selected if it works for you.

Comment: This is indeed a great start towards a perfect solution.